# docker on windows not starting after a fresh install (hyper-v)

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, docker, docker-for-windows

[my os version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrasC.png)

[virtualization enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsSQW.png)

[hyper-v enabled screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6gkv.png)

[hyper-v manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGrqN.png)

[hyper-v connect local screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vcKK.png)

[hyper-v Error  screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGbRS.png)
Translation of the text:

```
An error occurred when trying to connect to the server
 "DESKTOP-CP6UMCI" Check that the virtual computer management 
service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server
```

Hyper-v encountered an error when trying to access an object on the computer.
" DESKTOP-CP6UMCI " because the object is not found. The object may have been deleted. Verify that the virtual computer management 
service is running on the computer

[docker Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YoGw.png) Translation of the text:

```
Unable to create: The execution of the command has stopped, because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or the current parameter has the value Stop : Hyper-V encountered an error when trying to access an object on the computer "DESKTOP-CP6UMCI", because the object is not found. The object may have been deleted. Verify that the virtual computer management service is running on the computer.
in New-Switch,  : line 121
to ,  : line 411
   to Docker.Core.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Corepipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
   to Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 92
   to Docker.Actions.c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 74
   to Docker.WPF.TaskQueueue.c__DisplayClass19_0.b__1() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

(this error show up when i try to start docker or docker is starting at system boot up)

i need help i do not know why docker / hyper-v is doing this, laptop is omen-hp
i already try "MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof" command but nothing happen:(

Comment: Did you "Verify that the virtual computer management service is running on the computer"? Run `services.msc` and search for that service.

Comment: yes, is that the [one](https://i.imgur.com/1THNqkx.png)
"Hyper-V virtual computer management"

Comment: @Biswapriyo  I don't think it's the right [one](https://i.imgur.com/cSS5vsD.png)
"Virtualization Service Hyper-V Remote Desktop"

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by updating windows 10 pro 1803 to 1809